# create UIImageView with image from a link?

Tags: ios

I want to create UIImageView with image from a link.i don't know how to load image from link in background thread.I have used third-party library like-SDWebImage, which is really good.
But i want to know how to do this without any third-party library.
Please help!

THanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: Check `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method of `NSURLConnection`

Comment: Your suggestion is appreciable but if there is number of images to be loaded from different urls, then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very possible without any third party library,Try this.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100, 100)];
NSData *imageData;
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                // async thread 
                imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureUrl];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  // return to main thread 
                    imageView.image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
                });
            });
```